# Uncss Twitter Bootstrap Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, uncss

I want to make use of the grunt plugin "uncss". But I still misses some classes of the bootstrap modal. Right now my grunt setup for uncss looks like this:

```
uncss: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          ignore: [
            ".fade",
            ".fade.in",
            ".collapse",
            ".collapse.in",
            ".collapsing",
            ".alert-danger",
            // Modal
            ".modal",
            ".modal.fade.in",
            ".modal-dialog",
            ".modal-scrollbar-measure",
            ".modal-backdrop.fade",
            ".modal-backdrop.in",
            ".modal.fade.modal-dialog",
            ".modal.in.modal-dialog",
            ".modal-open",
            ".in",
            ".modal-backdrop",
            /\.open/
          ]
        },
        files: {
          'css/app.css': ['index.html']
        }
      }
    },
```

Someone know which classes I missed to add to uncss?

Comment: I am also waiting for an answer on this question. :/

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression to pick up all of the modal things:

```
/\.modal/
```